# How to run Java method with arguments from command line?

Tags: java, terminal

I am trying to run the following method in `Loader.java` from the command line:

```
public static void method(String path, String word)
```

As seen above, I must pass in the variables `path` and `word`, and I want the command line to display the `System.out.println()`'s in the method.

What command can I run to do this?

Note: when I run the following commands,

```
javac *.java
jar -cvf Loader.jar Loader.class
java -cp ./Loader.jar Loader
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: path/to/Loader (wrong name: Loader)
```

What must I do to successfully run `method` from the command line?

Here is minimum reproducible version of `Loader.java`:

```
public class Loader {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          method("my/path", "my_word");
     }
     public static void method(String path, String word) {
          System.out.println("Output after doing something");
     }
}
```

Comment: Post the complete code of `Loader.java`.

Comment: @user yes as seen above

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I have edited the question to include that.

Comment: Satya Vejus - Any update?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, when I run the code you are suggesting, I get `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: path/to/Loader (wrong name: Loader)`. Also I still don't know how to pass parameters from command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the following:

```
javac Loader.java
java Loader
```

In fact, if you are you Java-11 or above, you don't even need to use the first command i.e. you can directly use the following command:

```
java Loader.java
```

However, if you want to create a jar file and execute the class from it, execute the steps given below:

```
mkdir demo
cd demo
```

Now create/place `Loader.java` in this folder. Then,

```
javac *.java
jar -cvf loader.jar .
java -cp loader.jar Loader
```

Note that I've used a new directory, `demo` to make it clear but it is not necessary. Another thing you should notice is the `.` at the end of `jar` command which specifies the current directory.

### How to process command-line arguments?

`String[] args` parameter in `main` stores all the parameters from the command-line e.g. if you run the following program as `java Loader my/path my_word` from the command-line,

```
public class Loader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length >= 2) {
            method(args[0], args[1]);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Command line parameters are missing");
        }
    }

    public static void method(String path, String word) {
        System.out.println("Path: " + path);
        System.out.println("Word: " + word);
    }
}
```

the output will be

```
Path: my/path
Word: my_word
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, when I run the code you are suggesting, I get `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: path/to/Loader (wrong name: Loader)`. Also I still don't know how to pass parameters from command line.

Comment: @SatyaVejus - Did you try to create/place Loader.java in a separate folder as I've suggested? I've tested everything I've posted and I don't find any problem.

Comment: I am not sure I can place `Loader` in a separate folder because it requires other classes that I have made. It also processes a different file `dict.txt` in `method`. Also in your recent updated answer, what is the command line prompt for passing in `String[] args`?

Comment: The command is `java Loader my/path my_word` where `my/path` is the first parameter and will be stored into `args[0]` and `my_word` is the second parameter which will be stored into `args[1]`.

Comment: What happens when you run `jar -cvf loader.jar .` after running `javac *.java`? Do you see `loader.jar` file after that? If yes, `java -cp loader.jar Loader` will run successfully. If you want to pass parameters, you can run `java -cp loader.jar Loader my/path my_word` where `my/path` and `my_word` are parameters.

Comment: Yes, I do see `loader.jar`. However, I still get the error `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: path/to/Loader (wrong name: Loader)` when I run `java -cp loader.jar Loader`. Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Try `java -cp .:loader.jar Loader`

Comment: Ok it finally word when I moved to the parent folder dir.

Comment: Perfect! Wish you success!